# Describing where a Kleisli Triple fits into a Monad ontology

Tags: category-theory, monads

I'm trying to map a Kleisli triple onto my existing understanding of Monads.

I can represent my understanding of Monads like this: ([courtesy of Jim Duey's slides at 13](http://www.clojure.net/assets/ClojureWest13/abstractions.svg#%7Bstep%2013%7D))
[image]

Could you please point to the part on this diagram where Kleisli triples fit in - or even better - draw another diagram that this diagram can fit into that explains it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kleisli triples fit in the diagram exactly where you have "monads". Kleisli triples are equivalent to monads (you might say they are one presentation of monads).

I infer from the link that you are thinking about this in the context of programming languages? This question/answers might help: [What is a monad in FP, in categorical terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221395/what-is-a-monad-in-fp-in-categorical-terms/10932707#10932707).

Comment: (see also p.10 of  http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~dao29/lectures/cprg/cprg-lecture3-mspl-dorchard-notes.pdf)